# How to protect in IOS from EXC_BAD_ACCESS in recursive Algorithm

Tags: ios, recursion, stack-overflow, exc-bad-access

I am trying to do some simulations and math operations that are highly recursive and in some edge cases I overflow the call stack and get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal. It is unfeasable to change the algorithms to an iterative form since it is a lot of legacy code. And a recursion depth limit would not be useful because the use of memory is non deterministic.

Is there a way to detect the amount of stack available so I can cancel the operation gracefully?

Is it possible to implement a type of Stack Canary that I can continuously check is not overriden?

Comment: Have you figured this out yet, cause I have the same problem and no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If thread-safety is not a concern, use a static variable. Something like this:

```
int recurse(int something) {
  static int depth = 0;
  ++depth;
  if (depth > MAX_DEPTH) { // bail }

  ...
  int result = recurse(...);
  --depth;
  return result;
}
```

If thread-safety is a concern, you could pass `depth` as a parameter.